# Get the output of nested intermediate model wrapped by TimeDistributed layer

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network

This question is similar to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19362/how-to-obtain-output-of-intermediate-model-in-keras

I'm creating a neural architecture using the functional API as follows:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(50, embed_dim))

dense_layer = Dense(embed_dim, activation='tanh')(input1)
softmax_layer = Activation('softmax', name='attention')(dense_layer)

attention_mul = multiply([softmax_layer,input1])
vec_sum = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1))(attention_mul)

# Nested (Intermediate Model)
pre_model1 = Model(input1, vec_sum, name='news_attention')

input2 = Input(shape=(1, 50, embed_dim))
pre_cnn = TimeDistributed(pre_model1)(input2)
cnn = Conv1D(filters = 100, 
          kernel_size = 3, 
          padding = 'same',
          activation = 'relu')(pre_cnn)
flatten = Flatten()(cnn)
dropout = Dropout(0.5)(flatten)
final = Dense(hidden_dims, activation="relu")(dropout)

model = Model(input2, final)
```

Now I want to access the ouptut of "softmax_layer" which is a layer in the nested model, **pre_model1**. I tried to follow the solution in the [datascience stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19362/how-to-obtain-output-of-intermediate-model-in-keras). However, I couldn't get the nested model object(**pre_model1**) in the model summary like it said.

[model.summary()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwJ5B.png)

[model architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB4qp.png)

How can I get nested model object that is wrapped by TimeDistributedLayer ?

Thank you.